# What is the Unruh temperature for an observer at near the speed of light?

Tags: reference-frames, temperature, acceleration, relativity, unruh-effect

I have read about the Unruh effect where an accelerated observer would experience a radiation that a non accelerated observer wouldn't.
According to wikipedia the formula goes like this:

[image: 1]

My question is what is the maxima of this formula, with an observer travelling frpm rest to an arbitrary percertage of the speed of light.

Comment: Acceleration is not the same as speed

Comment: Of course, it would be for the observer accelerating from rest to an arbitrary percentage of c. Sorry if I didn't express myself well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acceleration in the equation for the Unruh temperature is the [proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration) i.e. it is the acceleration that the accelerating observer measures in their rest frame.

If we sit and watch an accelerating object, e.g. some rocket blasting away, then we will observe the acceleration of the rocket to tail off as it approaches the speed of light, because obviously the rocket can't end up going faster than light. However on the rocket the acceleration measured by the crew can remain constant indefinitely, limited only by how much fuel they can carry. The difference between the decreased acceleration we spectators observe and the constant proper acceleration the crew measure is due to the time dilation and length contraction between our two frames.

The point of this is that your question cannot be answered because it is ill posed. The Unruh temperature measured *on the rocket* is proportional to the proper acceleration measured *on the rocket*. If the proper acceleration is constant the Unruh temperature is constant and doesn't go through any maximum.

For we non-accelerated observers watching from the Earth there is no Unruh temperature because we aren't accelerating.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser and for pointing out the proper acceleration article, which I'll read to better understand the difference between the two reference frames.